# Couldn't get response on nodejs webhook when user sends location from messenger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, webhooks, facebook-messenger-bot

I made a intent called weather in dialog flow and when user asks weather in my city. The response I sent back to user is "send my location" quick replies and when user send back location, I don't know how to read response back in backend http webhook. Any ideas?

The image for dialogflow intent is below:
[image: dialogflow intent]

webhook code is as below:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
 //how to read location payloads here 
}
```

Comment: Did you check `req.body` field there should be the payload as string. If you registered the bodyparser json middleware for that route ("/") you might get an object.

Comment: I did checked it but the response sent on webhook is previous response while asking "weather in my city" and when user sends back payload it doesn't come back to my backend

Comment: What is this "Set this intent as end of conversation" setting about?

Comment: I tried disabling it too. It still doesn't work. On the second time the intent doesn't goes back to backend

Comment: To be sure your are aware of every webhook call, you might use a wildcard for your route and log every request comeing in `router.post("/*", async (req, res, next) => { /* log req.body here */ }`. Otherwise check your dialogFlow settings for your intents.